# Sharing on Facebook returns no images, even if go:image is present and if linter says ok

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

here is my headache situation:

I have my weblog's single article page, if I try to share this page with the facebook like button, or with the old sharing bookmarklet, I get no image on Facebook post preview, and of course I don't get any image on my Facebook page too.

I can hear you say, well, check it with linter, sure, that's what I did, and this is what I've found so far:

1. Linter returns no error and it shows the right thumb image
2. if "after" the linter passage, I try to share the same page again, well, I get the thumb.

Do you have any idea of what's going on?

here you can see an example: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Flegrandj.eu%2Farticle%2Falain_baczynsky

this is the original page: http://legrandj.eu/article/alain_baczynsky

well, I know at this point it's not easy do debug, because I've "linted" almost all pages, but you can trust me, no images.

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> if "after" the linter passage, I try to share the same page again, well, I get the thumb.

This is because you already tried to share them and they're now cached without images. If you want to get all pages fresh with image(s), you have to wait or re-lint every page you want to share in future. That's the only way to lift all caches immediately.

Comment: actually I wonder why it didn't return the image post at the first instance. And why it gets the image if I check it with linter. The page is always the same, I didn't change anything on it.

Comment: @Daniele: are you sure Facebook didn't hit that url you're trying to share before?

Comment: sorry, I really thank you for your time, but I just don't get it. This is how it happens. I have my page, I try to share it with Facebook like button, so yes, Facebook touches it, but his magic touch don't get the og:image. So I have an imageless post on Facebook wall. Then I touch it again with linter, to check it, linter says page is ok, there's even the image! Now if I share the same page again, as I did before, the very first time, with that same button, well, now I have the image. Sure Facebook overwrites his cache, with linter, but why the first time it didn't take the image?

Comment: @Daniele: You're hiding og: meta tags from normal users, right? I do not see it anywhere in your page, but Facebook does

Comment: sure, that's it. Hiding method is based on user agent string. Maybe linter uses facebookexternalhit/1.1 but they have another user agent for page sharing? Now it's not hidden anymore, let's see.